# Undefined variable error after form validated in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, validation

I am trying to use form validation for my form after user submits it. My view page has a variable that was passed by my controller. The view page works fine until I submit the form to validate. It gave me errors saying the variables passed by controller were undefined. I am not sure how to solve this. Any thoughts?

```
// Controller - status.php
public function load_view ()
{
    $this->load->model('project_query');
    $JNresults=$this->project_query->get_jobnumber();
    $data['JNresults']=$JNresults->result(); //pass to view
    $data['view']='form_view';
    $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
}

public function validate ()
{
    //validate form

    $data['error']='There are errors in your form.';
    $data['view']='form_view';
    $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
}
```

```
// View page - form_view.php
foreach ($JNresults as $row):    //work fine when first loaded. 
    echo $row->job_number;
endforeach;

echo form_open('status/validate');
echo validation_errors();
// input fields...
echo form_submit($submit);
echo form_close();
```

I get undefined variable `$JNresults` after I submit the form. I understand the view page don't recognize it because it was passed from the controller. I just want to know if anyone can help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `validate()` method, you aren't using `$data['JNresults']=$JNresults->result();` so the variable `$JNresults` never gets populated in your view.

The solution:

Validate the form in `load_view()`, and get rid the of `validate()` method:

```
public function load_view()
{
    // set validation rules
    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        // do something
    }

    $this->load->model('project_query');
    $JNresults=$this->project_query->get_jobnumber();
    $data['JNresults']=$JNresults->result(); //pass to view
    $data['view']='form_view';
    $this->load->view('include/template', $data);
}
```

Then change `form_open('status/validate')` to `form_open()` or `form_open('status/load_view')`.

It looks like you aren't using the `$data['error']`, which is fine because you don't need it. `validation_error()` returns an empty string if there are no errors, so if you want to add an extra message you can just check if it's empty:

```
if ($errors = validation_errors())
{
    echo 'There were errors:';
    echo $errors;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Madmartigan. I assume this is the best practice when you need to load view and validate the form?

Comment: It's what I suggest doing while you find your feet in Codeigniter, I'm still not sure what I think the best practice is, sometimes I try to implement true [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. It depends, really. Just make sure to `redirect()` after processing the form.

Answer (score 1):

In your second controller function you are not loading the JNresults variable, you have to add:

```
public function validate ()
{
    //validate form
    $JNresults=$this->project_query->get_jobnumber();
    $data['JNresults']=$JNresults->result(); //pass to view
    $data['error']='There are errors in your form.';
    $data['view']='form_view';
    $this->load->view('include/template',$data);
}
```

Also you are not calling a validation for the post data in that function.